# Grep and subset on levels of factor

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

> my_df[1,]
>   gene_id ENSG00000171680.16; transcript_id ENST00000400915.3; gene_type protein_coding; gene_status KNOWN; gene_name PLEKHG5; transcript_type protein_coding; transcript_status KNOWN; transcript_name PLEKHG5-002; exon_number 4; exon_id ENSE00003634700.1; level 2; protein_id ENSP00000383706.3; tag basic; tag appris_candidate; tag CCDS; ccdsid CCDS41241.1; havana_gene OTTHUMG00000000905.3; havana_transcript OTTHUMT00000002631.1;
>
> my_df[2,]
>   gene_id ENSG00000173662.15; transcript_id ENSG00000173662.15; gene_type protein_coding; gene_status KNOWN; gene_name TAS1R1; transcript_type protein_coding; transcript_status KNOWN; transcript_name TAS1R1; level 1; havana_gene OTTHUMG00000001441.2;
>   7734 Levels: gene_id ENSG00000007923.11; transcript_id ENSG00000007923.11; gene_type protein_coding; gene_status KNOWN; gene_name DNAJC11; transcript_type protein_coding; transcript_status KNOWN; transcript_name DNAJC11; level 2; havana_gene OTTHUMG00000001443.3; ...

my_df[n,]

................

I only would like to subset ENSG* contained in each row (14.000 rows and 1 column) of the full data frame. 
I tried to use the grep function but unfortunately it gives back integer(0).
Expected output:
gene_id ENSG00000007923.11
gene_id ENSG00000173662.15
.............

Can you please help me to solve this issue?

Kind regards

Comment: Please share example data and expected output instead of `str()`.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work.. it returns the full length row as output.

Comment: You should follow @mtoto's advice then and clarify your question

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use the pattern as:

```
pattern <- '[E][N][S][G]'
```

Use this pattern in grep() function which will return the matching row numbers.

Accordingly, you can subset the data frame.

Comment: @Bfu38 Is it necessary that in each tuple of data.frame, the gene_id ENSG* thing comes initially or it may occur anywhere in the row. Also, is it possible that gene_id exists in any row without ENSG* thing?